# docker container failed to start when mapping volume

Tags: docker

When I run this command to run docker(Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77156):

```
sudo docker run -p 18084:8070 -v /opt/dabai/app/config-center/docker-apollo/apollo-portal/target/apollo-portal-1.4.0-github:/apollo-portal:rw apollo-portal
```

The output is:

```
[daai@iZ3refzweg1d9dh94t9Z ~]$ sudo docker run -p 18084:8070 -v /opt/dabai/app/config-center/docker-apollo/apollo-portal/target/apollo-portal-1.4.0-github:/apollo-portal:rw apollo-portal
Fri May 31 07:59:06 UTC 2019 ==== Starting ==== 
Failed to start
Fri May 31 07:59:16 UTC 2019 Failed to start apollo-portal.jar, return code: 1
```

I use this command to check the docker's log:

```
docker logs ce518631ced
```

the output is the same.How do i detect where is the problem is? By the way, when I remove the volume mapping, the container starts up successfully.

Comment: That sounds like the volume mapping is hiding the jar file.  What's your goal with the volume mapping?  Do you have more details like the Dockerfile for the image?

Answer (score 0):

Copy container files to local machine to replace old mapping folder could solve this problem.

```
docker cp 12ba0764beff:/apollo-portal /opt/dabai/app/docker/apollo/apollo-portal
```

12ba0764beff is the container id.start docker with mapping:

```
sudo docker run -p 18084:8070 -v /apollo-portal /opt/dabai/app/docker/apollo/apollo-portal:/apollo-portal:rw apollo-portal
```